# Bones not moving in pose mode?

Tags: transforms, armature, bones, rigify

When ever I try to move or rotate a bone in pose mode, nothing happens. The bone stays frozen, not moving to any axes, no matter what bone I chose.. 
I tried rigify ready to use mesh but had the same issue.

Comment: Is the Armature not in "Rest position" ? You can check that in properties > Armature tab > section "Skeleton". If so, just switch to "Pose position" and retry.

Comment: nop. it's in pose position. if it would be in rest, there would be errors.

Comment: I had this problem and just discovered the "manipulate center points" option was enabled (shortcut: alt ,). It's the button to the right of the pivot center pulldown in the 3D viewport menu. Disabling it solved my problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try disabling *Manipulate center points*.
Here's a screenshot of the option:

[image: screen-shot]